# Как поменять размер массива байтов?

Tags: c#, сокет, tcp

Доброй ночи всем. Тут возникла одна очень глупая идея с передачей данных через TCPListener и TCPClient, но беда в том что мне надо принимать строи такого типа /deleteacc /createfile и пр. Так вот у меня есть массив:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; //Чтобы уже наверняка
```

Так вот, а текст у меня допусти на 5 символов(но я не знаю точную длину, она может быть разная), и мне надо чтобы длина массива была равна длине полученного текста, вот мой код:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 4000);

            listener.Start();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            string data;

                Console.WriteLine("Ждём подключений");

                TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                Console.WriteLine("Подключен клиент");

                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                int i;

                i = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                Console.WriteLine(buffer.Length);
                data = Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);

                if (data == "/createfile")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Создаю файл.");
                }

                Console.WriteLine(data);

                client.Close();

                Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

Простой ответ - изменить размер массива нельзя. Можно создать новый нужного размера, и скопировать данные из первого. Можно заранее передать размер блока данных, чтобы дать возможность другой стороне выделить массив нужного размера.

Answer (score 1):

Извините, может, я туплю, но что мешает сделать так:

```
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
```

Comment: > Gets the length of the data available on the stream. This property is not currently supported and always throws a NotSupportedException.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.length.aspx

Вообще, логично: длина сетевого потока заранее неизвестна.

Comment: а почему бы не узнавать размер потока когда он уже инициализирован?